# Explicit description of nilpotent cones

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, determinant, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, one can define its nilpotent cone $\mathcal{N}$ to be the subspace that consists of element $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $ad(x)$ is a nilpotent operator.

In the case that $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl_2}$, each $ad(x)$ is an endomorphism of the vector space $\mathfrak{sl_2}$. By choosing a basis, this gives a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Explicitly, for the standard basis $\beta=\{h, e, f\}$ and

$$x =  \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & -a
\end{pmatrix},$$

the matrix $[ad(x)]_\beta$ is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -c & b \\
-2b & 2a & 0 \\
2c & 0 & -2a
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

It is then a linear algebra exercise to show that the subset of nilpotent operators is exactly

$$ \mathcal{N} = \{ x \in \mathfrak{g} \,|\, \det(x)=0 \}.$$

The computation is **elementary but long**.. However, the result is quite elegant. I fail to spot any insight why the defining equation is given by the determinant.

#### Question

Is this a coincidence? In general, or at least for those semisimple Lie algebras, what are their nilpotent cones in terms of explicit equations?

Comment: "$\text{ad}(x)$ is nilpotent" is already an explicit set of equations, namely the equations given by $\text{ad}(x)^{\dim \mathfrak{g}} = 0$. The corresponding ideal is not radical though. Equivalently, and with equations of lower degree, the condition is that every coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of $\text{ad}(x)$ vanishes, which is again an explicit set of equations. I'm not sure if this ideal is radical or not.

Comment: Ah! I shouldn't have used the confusing notation $\mathfrak{n}$! And yes.. abstractly it's the defining equations are given by polynomials, but is it easy to write them explicitly out? As in the case of $sl_2$.. the defining equation is $det(x) = 0$ or simply $a^2+bc=0$.

Comment: Given the first result mentioned in Torsten's answer an equivalent condition for $x \in \mathfrak{sl}_n$ is that every coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of $x$ vanishes, which is about as explicit as it gets. This reduces directly to the vanishing of the determinant for $n = 2$; the trace automatically vanishes so you can ignore that one. For $n = 3$ you need the determinant and also the linear coefficient of the characteristic polynomial. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two different things at work here:

1. A rather deep theorem that says that for a semisimple Lie algebra written as matrices, an element $x$ is $ad$-nilpotent if and only if it is nilpotent as matrix.
2. A more coincidental thing, namely, that a matrix of the form $\pmatrix{a &b\\c&-a}$ is nilpotent if and only if its determinant is $0$. For bigger matrices, only one direction holds, and one cannot conclude anything from the determinant being zero. Example: $\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&0} \in \mathfrak{sl}_3$, in spite of having zero determinant, is not nilpotent in any reasonable sense of the word.

Comment: The first point reminded me a theorem I learned a few years ago, at which time I didn't appreciate as much. It's in Humphreys' intro to Lie algebra. Corollary (p.30): Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, $\phi: L \to gl(V)$ a finite dimensional representation of $L$. If $x = s+n$ is the abstract Jordan decomposition of $x \in L$, then $\phi(x) = \phi(s) + \phi(n)$ is the usual Jordan decomposition of $\phi(x)$. ... Is this the "rather deep theorem" that you mean?

Comment: Yes, or whatever that is a corollary to is the result which also gives what I wrote.